# Using mod rewrite to change query text

Tags: regex, apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, webserver

I'm an extreme novice at Apache, but I am trying very hard and doing my best to learn.  However I've run up against an issue and although I've searched extensively (spent the last 3+ hours trying different things to try to make it work, lol), I've still been unable to find anything that does exactly what I need.  However, (I think) this should be extraordinarily simple question for someone more versed in this than I.

What I'm needing is a simply RewriteRule that will take a URL (https://sample.example.com/login.htm?page=%2F), and when visited, redirect/change it to "https://sample.example.com/login.htm?page=%2Fui2.htm).  I've tried rewrite rules, redirects, conditions, etc....but nothing I do gets there perfectly.  I feel like I'm really, really, really close but I can't quite cross that last step.  Here's what I have in the virtual host file this site matches to:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName sample.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/login\.htm$" "/login.htm?page=%2Fui2.htm" [R,L]


ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location />
        ProxyPass http://192.168.x.x:38374/
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.x.x:38374/
</Location>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

</IfModule>
```

(the internal IP and domain names above are obviously masked)

I know the input text for the rewrite is working with certainty, it's just the re-written part that's failing.  Everything works, except that it redirects me to https://sample.example.com/login.htm?page=Fui2.htm (i.e. it removes the "%2" part). Therein lies my problem.

Comment: 1 more attempt. Keep it as it is and use B and NE flags also. `[NE,B,R,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `%2` part with `\`s

Comment: I tried changing the "%2" to "\%2" which didn't work...Are you saying to try "\%\2"?

Comment: @ohlin5 try `\%2` and remove the double quotes from both regex string and replacement string.

Comment: I've tried both the suggestions the other poster here suggested, looks like he keeps editing it :) Anyways the neither worked...Most recent one redirects to https://sample.example.com/login.htm?page=Fui2.htm

Comment: OK I'll try that.  If this doesn't work it might be time for bed and to approach it tomorrow or Saturday with a clean head lol :)

Comment: @ohlin5 :). I am doing the guesswork because I can't test it :D

Comment: Haha well I still appreciate it :) Latest attempt (removal of double quotes and \ before the %2 redirects to https://sample.example.com/login.htm?page=%252Fui2.htm

Comment: @ohlin5 1 more attempt. Keep it as it is and use B flag also. [B,R,L]. And also NE `[NE,B,R,L]`

Comment: Unfortunately still the same URL after redirect that way too - https://sample.example.com/login.htm?page=%252Fui2.htm

Comment: @ohlin5 did you use NE flag also?

Comment: Hold up might be on to something there with both flags...testing

Comment: OK so great news is that fixes the URL...Bad news is it still doesn't load as I now get caught in a redirect loop (browser says site redirected too many times and throws error).  Thoughts there?

Comment: @ohlin5 `"/login.htm\?page=%2F$"` Try using this as a regex.

Comment: Without the double quotes I assume?  Or with?

Comment: With the double quotes.

Comment: OK it'll be just a minute my TeamViewer is being dumb lol.  Can I ask you what difference the with vs without double quotes makes?

Comment: You can use both ways I guess. I read the apache document where it was without the double quotes. Other place it was with double quotes. Don't know what's the exact difference. So I was just going for trial and error. I have zero experience with apache but I know regex a little bit.

Comment: The problem with redirect loop is that your regex is matching both the urls and then redirecting it. The same regex must not match the second URL (To which you are redirecting the first).

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I saw it both ways too lol.  So with that regard string you had me try, it now fails to match at all (doesn't redirect, goes straight to my internal IP with no URL change).  I agree the regex needs to just be more specific somehow to prevent the redirect loop, but for some reason that one's not matching...

Comment: The problem is Apache doesn't by default compare the regex to the query as well...Maybe I can find a way to force that

Comment: Now's when I need an Apache expert to step in haha :) I'm gonna call it a night and approach this with a fresh head another day.  We're super close, just need to find a way to make the URL only match that regex on the first load.

Comment: @ohlin5 Yeah all the best bro :) Gnite. Way too many comments, broke the SO rules.

Comment: I got it!!!  "RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=%2F$" (right above the rewrite, without the double quotes) did the trick!  Thanks so much for the awesome help man!!

Comment: @ohlin5 CONGO! :D